# entity framework down migration on sql-express (or azure)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-server-express, entity-framework-migrations

I use Entity Framework 6 with Code-First configuration `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled=true` and I would like to execute a migration down on my database which is hosted in SQL-express server.

In debug mode I can use the Visual Studio console and execute "Update-Database -TargetMigration myMigration", but what about with a SQL-express database?

Comment: Same process. Change you connection string to point to your SQL Express database. Alternatively, you can generate a script to update the other database.

Comment: @SteveGreene I have found the solution that is similar to Azure SQL database environment! Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for migrate down a SQL Express database, in NuGet Pagage Manager Console type:

```
Update-Database 
-TargetMigration {migrationName} 
-ConnectionString "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog={databaseName};Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" 
-ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" 
-Verbose
```